# How to sort a tridimensional array [5][5][5] using shellsort in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, shellsort

Hi everyone i have a problem with my program, i have a tridimensiona array but i can sort with shellsort.I can show the array, but the void ordenacionShell cant sort my array,can anyone help me please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void intercambiar(int& x, int& y);

void intercambiar(int& x, int& y)
{
int aux = x;
x = y;
y = aux;
}
void ordenacionShell(int a[5][5][5], int n)

 {
int salto, i, j, k,j1,j2,k1,k2;
salto = n / 2;
while (salto > 0)
{
for (i = salto; i < n; i++)
{
    j = i - salto;
    j1= i - salto;
    j2= i - salto;
    while (j >= 0 )
    {
        k = j + salto;
            k1 = j + salto;
                k2 = j + salto;
        if (a[j][j1][j2] <= a[k][k1][k2])
        {j = -1; // par de elementos ordenado
            j1 = -1;
            j2 = -1;}
        else
        {
            cout<<"intercambio: "<<"";
            cout<<a[j][j1][j2]<<" ";
            cout<<a[k][k1][k2]<<"\n";
            intercambiar(a[j][j1][j2], a[k][k1][k2]);

            j -= salto;
            j1 -= salto;
            j2 -= salto;


        }
    }
  }
   salto = salto / 2;
   cout<<"Salto: "<<salto<<"\n";
  }
}


int main()
{
int a[5][5][5] = {
    { {1,2,9,4,5}, {6,7,17,9,10}, {11,12,16,14,15}, {16, 17, 22, 19, 20},   {21,22, 20, 24, 25} },

   {26,25,28,29,30}, {31,29,33,34,35 }, {36,30,38,39,40}, {41,42,49,44,45},      {46, 47, 34, 49, 50},  },

   { {51, 52, 49, 54, 55}, {56,57,58,50,60}, {61,62,63,66,65}, {66, 67, 68, 69, 71}, {71, 70, 73, 74, 75}, },

 { {76, 75, 78, 79, 80}, {81,82,73,84,85}, {86,77,88,89,90}, {91, 82, 93, 94, 95}, {96, 91, 98, 99, 100}, },

  { {101, 100, 103, 104, 105}, {106,105,108,109,110}, {121, 112, 113, 114, 115}, {116, 117, 118, 119, 121}, {121, 122, 123, 124, 123} }
};

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
   {
         for(int l=0;l<5;l++)
   {
    cout<<a[i][j][l]<<",";

   }
  }}
   ordenacionShell( a,5);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
      for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
         for(int l=0;l<5;l++)
       {
       cout<<a[i][j][l]<<",";

    }
 }}


  return 0;
}
```

The original Shellsort function for a simple array correctly working is this:

```
void ordenacionShell(int a[], int n)
{
int salto, i, j, k;
salto = n / 2;
while (salto > 0)
{
for (i = salto; i < n; i++)
{
    j = i - salto;
    while (j >= 0)
    {
        k = j + salto;
        if (a[j] <= a[k])
            j = -1; // par de elementos ordenado
        else
        {
            cout<<"intercambio: "<<"";
            cout<<a[j]<<" ";
            cout<<a[k]<<"\n";
            intercambiar(a[j], a[k]);
            j -= salto;
        }
    }
}
salto = salto / 2;
cout<<"Salto: "<<salto<<"\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130673/sorting-multidimensional-array-in-c

Comment: nitpick -- `intercambiar()` is the same as `std::swap()` =)

Comment: What exactly does it mean to sort a 3-dimensional array? Are you treating the whole array as if it were 1-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Your array initialization is wrong. You have wandering commas everywhere.

Example:

```
int a[5][5][5] = {
    { {1,2,9,4,5}, {6,7,17,9,10}, {11,12,16,14,15}, {16, 17, 22, 19, 20},   {21,22, 20, 24, 25} },

   {26,25,28,29,30}, {31,29,33,34,35 }, {36,30,38,39,40}, {41,42,49,44,45},      {46, 47, 34, 49, 50},  },
//                                                                                    check this out ^
```

Does fixing that fix your issue?